Filter the pull request in GitHub
I am trying to filter the Pull Requests in Github If particular PR is there we don't need to create PR for that I have included below code but its saying error line 61: syntax error: unexpected end of file
Usual PR name should be like = Checking drift in the resource: $RESOURCE
echo "Checking if a pull request for '$RESOURCE' already exists"
existing_pr=$(curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $(pat-token)" \
  https://github.mytab.com/api/v3/repos/rep/rep-infra/pulls?state=open&head=drift-rep-${RESOURCE} \
  | jq '.[] | select(.title | test("Checking drift in the resource: '"$RESOURCE"'"))')
if [ -n "$existing_pr" ]; then
  echo "Pull request already exists for '$RESOURCE'. Skipping PR creation."
else
  echo "Creating Pull Request now"

Is any wrong with logic ?

You need fi at the end, to close out the if/then/else.

since the gh cli already does this check, you could sniff out what API requests it's making on your network if you want a way to see if you're on the right track.

Possibly fatal bugs:

You appear to be missing a fi after an if.
You appear to have some & in an unquoted string.
It seems to me that "$RESOURCE" in the jq command is not going to appear in double quotes to jq.

Other considerations:

jq has an --exit-status flag that is probably more suitable than [ -n "$existing_pr" ].
Consider passing RESOURCE into jq as a variable.
Are you sure you don't want to use gh for this?

Perhaps:
echo "Checking if a pull request for '$RESOURCE' already exists"
gh_token=$(pat-token)
url="https://github.mytab.com/api/v3/repos/rep/rep-infra/pulls?state=open&head=drift-rep-${RESOURCE}"
jq='.[] |
    select(.title |
           test("Checking drift in the resource: $resource"))'
json=$(curl -sfH "Authorization: Bearer $gh_token" "$url")
if jq --exit-status --arg resource "$RESOURCE" "$jq"; then
    echo "Pull request already exists for '$RESOURCE'. Skipping PR creation."
else
    echo 'Creating Pull Request now'
fi


url dont we need to pass ?

@pks lol, of course, thanks. Edited.

How it works with gh  ?

@pks with gh if you try to do gh pr create … on an existing PR, it will just tell you it already exists. That's it.
